# Getting authentication error while creating a Dataflow template pipeline with beam 2.0

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Please refer to this link on how to run Java based Cloud Dataflow - https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-maven

Created template using below command

```
mvn archetype:generate \
      -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.beam \
      -DarchetypeArtifactId=beam-sdks-java-maven-archetypes-examples \
      -DarchetypeVersion=2.16.0 \
      -DgroupId=org.example \
      -DartifactId=word-count-beam \
      -Dversion="0.1" \
      -Dpackage=org.apache.beam.examples \
      -DinteractiveMode=false
```

and then To run the job using the DataflowRunner executed the below command

```
mvn -Pdataflow-runner compile exec:java \
      -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount \
      -Dexec.args="--project=<PROJECT_ID> \
      --stagingLocation=gs://<STORAGE_BUCKET>/staging/ \
      --output=gs://<STORAGE_BUCKET>/output \
      --runner=DataflowRunner"
```

But when trying to run above command getting following error 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to construct instance from factory method DataflowRunner#fromOptions(interface org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions)

Comment: Is there more to the error that you are getting?

Comment: Have you followed [before you begin](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-maven#before-you-begin) steps before using Dataflow? If so, have you set up the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable(`echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`)? Does the service account used have the necessary [roles](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/access-control#permissions_and_roles) to run the job?

Comment: Thanks, Ankur now it's working

Comment: @ajit singh can you confirm that my suggestion helped you? If yes, I'll create an answer, to help the future contributors with their research.

Comment: Yes Ankur its working fine. Your suggestion worked.

Comment: @ajit singh Thanks for confirmation, I added the answer with solution, please consider accpeting/upvoting the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was said in a comment, to work off `java.lang.RuntimeException` error, there is a need to follow [before you begin](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-maven#before-you-begin) steps for Java and Apache Maven before running Dataflow jobs. Steps include:

1. Setting up authentication and the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to the path of the JSON file that contains service account key
2. Creating a Cloud Storage bucket
3. Installing the Java Development Kit (JDK) and Apache Maven. Verify that the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is set and points to JDK installation.